# Извлечь слово из строки (url)

Tags: c#, ios, url, xamarin

Ниже приведена строка, получаемая после запроса (Url):

```json
{"sentences":[{"trans":"Приветствую","orig":"Hello","backend":1}],"src":"en","spell":{}}
```

Как вы могли догадаться, запрос заключается в переводе слова.

Необходимо вытаскивать слова из метки "trans". В данном случае это "Приветствую".

Comment: Это json, но в нем синтаксическая ошибка, вы точно правильно скопировали ответ от сервера? И скажите, какая целевая версия фреймворка у приложения?

Comment: Разве это не JSON?

Comment: @aepot Ответ от сервера приходит такой же, как если бы я отправил запрос в поисковой строке (скачивается файл .txt). К сожалению, ранее я пытался и не смог узнать версию фреймворка.(Visual Studio 8.1.5)

Comment: Если по-простому, то установите NuGet пакет Newtonsoft.Json, и вот так `string text = JsonConvert.DeserealizeObject<dynamic>(responseText).sentences[0].trans;`. Но я советую вам поподробней ознакомиться с десереализацией в Json.NET. Материалов в сети просто огромное количество, тема суперпопулярная.

Comment: Студию ставьте [последнюю](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/), там есть бесплатная Community версия. 8.7 последняя сейчас для мака, если я не ошибаюсь.

Comment: @aepot Благодарю, но я ранее уже писал указанный вами код, возникает ошибка, связанная с версией фрэймворка: " Error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard..."

Comment: NuGet пакет Newtonsoft.Json установили? Но для начала обновите студию.

Comment: Кстати после установки пакета в самом начале кода вам нужно добавить `using Newtonsoft.Json;`, но студия это должна и так либо сделать, либо подсказать.

Comment: @aepot Да, у меня последная версия 2019. Директивы использованы. Если верить интернету, нужно изменить версию .NET. Но как оказалось это не так просто

Comment: Если проект небольшой, создайте новый проект и просто перенесите код. А так, правой кнопкой на проекте в обозревателе решения, Свойства, там вкладка Приложение и выбрать целевой фреймворк.